# Unusually large gap between lowermost icon and taskbar in Windows 8.1

Tags: taskbar, icons, windows-8.1

When I have an icon located close to my taskbar, it looks like this:

[image]

I'm using Windows 8.1. I started a game that for some reason defaulted to 1024x768. I went ahead and changed the in-game resolution. But when I quit, I noticed an abnormally big gap between the lowermost icon and the taskbar. Apparently, the desktop resolution also changed to 1024x768 so I changed it back to 1920x1080 but the gap is still present.

Also, there's a gap on the edge of the right side of my desktop and I'm unable to place icons to the rightmost of my desktop.

Is there a way to revet this to default? I tried rebooting to no avail.

Comment: Do you have 'align icons to grid' on? (right click on desktop>> view). Cliff

Comment: Yes I do have it on.

Comment: Turn it off & back on, see if that helps.  If not try turn it off. Change the resolution and then change it back. Turn it on again.  I'm not sure this will do it, but I think some combinations of this sort might reset it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the icons got smaller that's why it looks farther.

Click once on the Desktop to make sure it is selected, then Hold CTRL and scroll UP or DOWN with your mouse. This will change the size of the icons along with their positioning (depending on the size, Windows decides how to position them in the grid).